# PHP CURL seems to be ignoring cookie jar/file

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm using this....

```
    function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $p=NULL)
    {

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/TestCookies");


        if ($p) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
        }
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

And I'm making a call like this...

```
        $Headers = array(
                "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*\/*;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");


        $a = $this->cURL("https://www.mysite.com/",$Headers, null);
```

I'd expect this to receive a cookie and write it to the file `/tmp/TestCookies`.

The site definitely returns `Set-Cookie` headers - I can see them if I dump `$a`, however, the file in question is never created.

In case it's a permissions issue, I created it with `touch` and `chmod 777`'d it - The file now exists but it's empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_COOKIEFILE` is read from, and only `_COOKIEJAR` is written to.

Comment: sort of mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1861824/345031

Comment: Thanks for the info - if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [curl constants](http://php.net/curl_setopt#~COOKIEJAR) are split into

- `CURL_COOKIEFILE` as the cookies.txt source which is **read** from
- and `CURL_COOKIEJAR` as the datastore that is **written** back to

You do have to provide `_COOKIEFILE` with an empty string to enable it IIRC, but `_COOKIEJAR` if you want them stored. Normally set both options to the same name.

Comment: Thanks mario - In my case, I tried providing one or the other but never both.

Comment: It's been turned into `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` since.