# PHP using cURL to loginto a website

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a website Using cURL I have read many answers on this website and still not able to get it. Please can someone help me find a solution

```
$url = 'https://secure.chess.com/login';

$postfields = "c1=USERNAME&loginpassword=PASSWORD&rememberme=";

$cookie = "cookie.txt";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: Paste your code, any errors, `curl_info` dumps, etc. Question is too tiny to even begin trying.

Comment: this should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872071/php-curl-seems-to-be-ignoring-cookie-jar-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a lot of post variables, among which an important state hash which has to be fetched before posting:

```
c1:USERNAME
loginpassword:PASSWORD
Qform__FormControl:btnLogin
Qform__FormEvent:QClickEvent
Qform__FormParameter:
Qform__FormCallType:Server
Qform__FormUpdates:
Qform__FormCheckableControls:rememberme
Qform__FormState:9661e98ced2596072a3ca5d70cd57ff5
Qform__FormId:LoginForm
```

An incorrect `Qform_FormState` yields absolutely no error messages, which proves to be confusing. You have to get the page first, rip out the `Qform_FormState` hash from the HTML and submit it along. There's also an occasional `c4` CAPTCHA field.

I was able to do this without much ado:

```
curl https://secure.chess.com/login -v | grep -Po '(?<=Qform__FormState" value=").*(?=")'
# 9b6b7d849c1d4fa16ed25b7b886cf88b
# note Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vvtk4stb22e34ac7jhg7m6i142; path=/; domain=.chess.com

curl \
    --header "Cookie: PHPSESSID=vvtk4stb22e34ac7jhg7m6i142" \
    --data="c1=USERNAME&loginpassword=PASSWORD... *snip* ...&Qform__FormState=9b6b7d849c1d4fa16ed25b7b886cf88b ..." \
    https://secure.chess.com/login -v
```

Comment: So I am missing form information? So how would I implement what you have in PHP?

Comment: You are indeed; I just answered your question as to why your doesn't work. Based on the information above just make sure you supply all the form field, and get the `FormState` right (extract from a `GET` first, use `SimpleXML` for example).