# Get html code from a page sending a cookie with curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm making a web and one of its functions need to get content from itself. Using curl with the following function:

```
function get_page_code($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo "\n<br />";
    $contents = '';
    } else {
    curl_close($ch);
    }
    if (!is_string($data) || !strlen($data)) {                      
    $data = '';
    }                           
    return $data;
}
```

The issue appears when I noticed I need to have a cookie so the content I want to get actually appears, so my question is how can I send cookies with this curl function? Of course I've those cookies on my computer but once sent the request to get the html code of the introduced url those cookies are not there.
Cookies I want to send with curl:

```
session: ab1b298aslc
gender: m
```

I'd grateful with any help :-)

EDIT:
Tried adding this lines to the function and nothing happened:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: gender=m"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: session=ab1b298aslc"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl cookie handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860544/curl-cookie-handling)

Comment: @Scriptman can't honestly see clearly the answer

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and point them both to the same writable file. cURL will handle the cookie then. You can remove the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` things.

Comment: where should that writable file be? In my server? What should I write on it? I want it to access the introduced url using the cookies i wrote above. Should them be on it? Thanks for your patience